# How to increase or decrease number of pods in Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I have one requirement based on some input value I need to decide the number of active pods I have, let's say in beginning the number would be 1, so there we need to start one pod after some time if number goes to 3, I need to start 2 more pods.

Next day it could happen number goes back to 1, so I need to accordingly remove 2 pods and keep 1 active. How can this be achieved in Kubernetes?

Comment: just edit/patch deployment, or scale up/down?

Comment: I tried this "kubectl scale deployment <deployement name> --replicas=3" that worked , is this only option we have or any alternative to handle this?

Comment: You can `kubectl apply` the deployment with new replicas number.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve this. The most obvious and manual one would be to use `kubectl scale [--resource-version=version] [--current-replicas=count] --replicas=COUNT (-f FILENAME | TYPE NAME)` as per [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#scale) or [this tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/scale/scale-interactive/). You can also consider taking advantage of Kubernetes autoscaling (Horizontal Pod Autoscaler and Cluster Autoscaler) described in [this article](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2016/07/autoscaling-in-kubernetes/) and [this document](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/).